# How to call a method after an Ajax update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've two selectOneMenu: The first selects which object (region, grades, age) the user wants and the second filter it.

E.g:

Region has west, north, south and east

Grades has A, B, C and D

So when the user select a "group by" option, the listener calls *onChangeGroupBy* which loads the whole list of the option selected. So if the user selected Region then *onChangeGroupBy* sets *selectedFilterBy* = [West, North, South, East].

Also, I've a filter that I update calling *flyoutId:cardsPanelId*. This second filter uses the same inputs selected by the user on these 2 selectOneMenu here. The method *onChangeFilterBy* filter the list to draw the charts and also set the inputs for this second filter.

The problem is: I want to select group by = grades and filter = D. At the moment that I change the option between A, B, C and D the second filter and the charts updates correctly. After that, if I select group by = region then my filter is updated to west, north, south and east BUT *onChangeFilterBy* isn't called therefore the filter and charts aren't update but I need to update it.

How can I do this? I tried to force the onChangeGroupBy to call onChangeFilterBy in the end of method but this causes problems bc sometimes the filterBy contains old values. E.g: filterBy = [A, B, C, D] but selectedGroupBy is Region.

xhtml

```
<p:outputPanel id="selects" styleClass="selects">
              <p:outputPanel id="groupPanel" styleClass="select-panel">
                  <p:outputLabel for="groupDashboardBy" value="Group by" styleClass="select-label"/>
                  <p:selectOneMenu id="groupDashboardBy" value=“#{bean.selectedGroupBy}">
   <f:selectItems value=“#{bean.groupBy}"/>
   <p:ajax update="@(.dashboards) filterPanel flyoutId:cardsPanelId" process="@this" listener="#{topicBean.dashboardHandler.onChangeGroupBy()}" oncomplete="dashboardCharts.loadDashboards()"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
              </p:outputPanel>
              <p:outputPanel id="filterPanel" styleClass="select-panel">
                  <p:outputLabel for="filterDashboard" value=“#{bean.selectedGroupBy}" styleClass="select-label"/>
                  <p:selectOneMenu id="filterDashboard" value=“#{bean.selectedFilterBy}">
                      <f:selectItems value=“#{bean.filterBy}" />
                      <p:ajax update="@(.dashboards) filterPanel flyoutId:cardsPanelId" process="@this" listener=“#{bean.onChangeFilterBy()}" oncomplete="dashboardCharts.loadDashboards()"/>
                  </p:selectOneMenu>
              </p:outputPanel>
          </p:outputPanel>
```

bean

```
public void onChangeGroupBy() {
        switch (selectedGroupBy) {
            case REGION:
                this.setFilterBy(regionSelectItems);
                onChangeFilterBy();
                break;
            case GRADEs:
                this.setFilterBy(gradesSelectItems);
                onChangeFilterBy();
                break;
        }
    }

public void onChangeFilterBy() {
   String selectedGroupBy = this.selectedGroupBy;
   List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
   this.model.resetFilters();

   switch (selectedGroupBy) {
      case REGION:
            this.model.setSelectedRegion(Collections.singletonList(selectedFilterBy));
            for (Card card : allCards) {
               //filter in the list and add in cards
               }
        
         generateChart(chartOne, cards);
         generateChart(chartTwo, cards);
         generateChart(chartThree, cards);
         break;
      case GRADES:
        
            this.model.setSelectedGrades(Collections.singletonList(selectedFilterBy));
            for (Card card : allCards) {
               //filter in the list and add in cards
            }
         }
         generateChart(chartOne, cards);
         generateChart(chartTwo, cards);
         generateChart(chartThree, cards);
         break;
   }
   this.model.secondFilter();
}
```

Comment: You don't show whether your bean is Requestcoped or another scope?  Also process="@this" will only process that SelectOne so if you are using a RequestScoped bean the other value of the other SelectOne is not being submitted and thus will always be NULL.

Answer (score -3):

I believe what you need to do is to add an **event** attribute to you **p:ajax** tag.

In particular:

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="@(.dashboards) filterPanel flyoutId:cardsPanelId"  process="@this" listener="#{topicBean.dashboardHandler.onChangeGroupBy()}" oncomplete="dashboardCharts.loadDashboards()"/>
```

That will ensure that the listener is invoked when a selection is changed.

Comment: Why? There are default events. In case of  `p:selectOneMenu` it is `valueChange`.